# How can i save HashMap<String, Any> type in Realm DB on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

How can I save a Hashmap that I want to have Any value to realm db? The Any type can be an object, a list, or a different hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

follow code:

```
open class KeyValue<K, V> : RealmObject {
var key: K? = null
var value: V? = null
}
```

and

```
calss yourEntyity : RealmObject {
....
var listHashMap : RealmList<KeyValue<String,String>> =  realmListOf()   
}
```